# Xml parsing with Elements of Element

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, parsing, windows-phone-8

I have a xml file like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Chapters</string>
        <key>Items</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>XYZ</string>

            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>ABC</string>

            </dict>
              </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>ChaptersONE</string>
        <key>Items</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>ASDF</string>

            </dict>
               </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I have a class like this:

```
class Chapter
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
}
```

How do i parse this xml and assign to the Chapter as list ?

I have tried the below :

```
List<Chapters> List = (from d in doc.Root.Element("array").Elements("dict")
                       select new HighwayCode
                       {
                           Title = (string)d.Element("string"),
                           SubTitle = d.Element("array")
                                        .Elements("dict")
                                        .Elements("string")
                                        .Select(s => (string)s)
                                        .ToList()
                       }).ToList();
```

But here the SubTitle is a list but i need that as a string

Comment: Maybe this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498467/parent-children-xml-to-dto-object-model-with-linq

Comment: ok post the full xml so i can copy paste it , 
and then describe what you want your output to be phrased as , take some time to make it clear ,because you question is barley readable,
and i will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean comma-delimited string? Use `String.Join`:

```
List<Chapters> List = (from d in doc.Root.Element("array").Elements("dict")
                       select new HighwayCode
                       {
                           Title = (string)d.Element("string"),
                           SubTitles = String.Join(",", d.Element("array")
                                                         .Elements("dict")
                                                         .Elements("string")
                                                         .Select(s => (string)s))
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: This works, but in my UI it displays items like XYZ,ABC in LongListSelector but i need them one below the other

Comment: So you do need a list... and problem is you don't know how to bind it into `LongListSelector`...

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek can you please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146447/linq-to-xml-with-nested-dictionary-and-array#comment33605276_22146447

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290982/parse-xml-with-varying-key