# Broad thoughts on XML nodes to SQL through datatables?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

Can't get more specific on this one yet.  I'm newish to C# and have a need to create an app to restore parts of our database...

I have a series of separate XML files that span across a few different folders. Say \FOLDER\P_0001\P_000002.xml and then \FOLDER\P_0002\P_000065.xml  (The initial folder is always the same but the amount of P_000X folders is always different.  Those being the folders that have multiple XML files in them.

Here is the format of the XML's that need to be read.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<EXAMS>
  <EXAM id="15" majver="1" minver="1" width="1128" height="910">
    <NAME xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string">Artefact reduced program</NAME>
    <PATIENT id="2" />
    <OBJECTS>
      <TAKE dbid="116" height="1280" width="2648">
        <VIEW majver="1" minver="2" maximized="0" x="0" y="122" width="1124" height="653" vx="199" vy="0" vWidth="2248" vHeight="1280" rotation="0" type="XP" regio="01" position="" orientation="" title="01XP 12.03.05: P1A, Ansicht Artefact reduced prog.." macroDbId="1" flippedHoriz="0" flippedVert="0" inverted="0" brightness="0" contrast="0" xPelsPerMeter="9259" yPelsPerMeter="9259" calibrated="0" calibrationFactor="1000">
          <PROPERTIES>
            <PROPERTY name="NGDevicePluginData" value="" />
            <PROPERTY name="NGPostProcessing" value="" />
            <PROPERTY name="NGDoseValues" value="" />
          </PROPERTIES>
          <DIAGNOSIS x="0" y="136" width="0" height="0" />
        </VIEW>
      </TAKE>
    </OBJECTS>
  </EXAM>
  <EXAM id="16" majver="1" minver="1" width="1128" height="910">
    <NAME xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string">Ceph</NAME>
    <PATIENT id="2" />
    <OBJECTS>
      <TAKE dbid="120" height="2136" width="2808">
        <VIEW majver="1" minver="2" maximized="0" x="4" y="447" width="561" height="440" vx="2" vy="1" vWidth="2805" vHeight="2135" rotation="0" type="XC" regio="03" position="" orientation="" title="03XC 28.07.04: 30x23, Ansicht Ceph" macroDbId="1" flippedHoriz="0" flippedVert="0" inverted="0" brightness="0" contrast="0" xPelsPerMeter="9615" yPelsPerMeter="9615" calibrated="0" calibrationFactor="1000">
          <PROPERTIES>
            <PROPERTY name="NGDevicePluginData" value="" />
            <PROPERTY name="NGPostProcessing" value="" />
            <PROPERTY name="NGDoseValues" value="" />
          </PROPERTIES>
          <DIAGNOSIS x="4" y="460" width="0" height="0" />
        </VIEW>
      </TAKE>
      <TAKE dbid="121" height="2136" width="1756">
        <VIEW majver="1" minver="2" maximized="0" x="598" y="450" width="351" height="440" vx="1" vy="1" vWidth="1755" vHeight="2135" rotation="0" type="XC" regio="04" position="" orientation="" title="04XC 23.08.05: -, Ansicht Ceph" macroDbId="1" flippedHoriz="0" flippedVert="0" inverted="0" brightness="0" contrast="0" xPelsPerMeter="9615" yPelsPerMeter="9615" calibrated="0" calibrationFactor="1000">
          <PROPERTIES>
            <PROPERTY name="NGDevicePluginData" value="" />
            <PROPERTY name="NGPostProcessing" value="" />
            <PROPERTY name="NGDoseValues" value="" />
          </PROPERTIES>
          <DIAGNOSIS x="598" y="463" width="0" height="0" />
        </VIEW>
      </TAKE>
      <TAKE dbid="118" height="2136" width="1756">
        <VIEW majver="1" minver="2" maximized="0" x="1" y="2" width="351" height="440" vx="1" vy="1" vWidth="1755" vHeight="2135" rotation="0" type="XC" regio="01" position="" orientation="" title="01XC 02.09.04: -, Ansicht Ceph" macroDbId="1" flippedHoriz="0" flippedVert="0" inverted="0" brightness="0" contrast="-9" xPelsPerMeter="9615" yPelsPerMeter="9615" calibrated="0" calibrationFactor="1000">
          <PROPERTIES>
            <PROPERTY name="NGDevicePluginData" value="" />
            <PROPERTY name="NGPostProcessing" value="" />
            <PROPERTY name="NGDoseValues" value="" />
          </PROPERTIES>
          <DIAGNOSIS x="1" y="15" width="0" height="0" />
        </VIEW>
      </TAKE>
      <TAKE dbid="119" height="2136" width="1800">
        <VIEW majver="1" minver="2" maximized="0" x="358" y="1" width="360" height="440" vx="0" vy="1" vWidth="1800" vHeight="2135" rotation="0" type="XC" regio="03" position="" orientation="" title="03XC 02.09.04: -, Ansicht Ceph" macroDbId="1" flippedHoriz="0" flippedVert="0" inverted="0" brightness="0" contrast="0" xPelsPerMeter="9615" yPelsPerMeter="9615" calibrated="0" calibrationFactor="1000">
          <PROPERTIES>
            <PROPERTY name="NGDevicePluginData" value="" />
            <PROPERTY name="NGPostProcessing" value="" />
            <PROPERTY name="NGDoseValues" value="" />
          </PROPERTIES>
          <DIAGNOSIS x="358" y="14" width="0" height="0" />
        </VIEW>
      </TAKE>
    </OBJECTS>
  </EXAM>
```

What needs to be done is to read certain nodes in the xml and then add them into different rows in the SQL.  Problem is, the names are different.  Say, "NAME" in the XML is actually going into the tGrpSName in the TGroupRaw table in the SQL......

But I'm lost.  I'd assume that I'll be first reading the XML into a dataset in this manner.

```
string path = "C:\\PDATA\\P_0000\\P_000002.xml";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(path);
```

Then I'd need to find a way to map the Nodes to a different name and then insert into SQL. 
After I get that complete and working normally I could find a way to iterate through all of the individual xml files and do the same with each.

But I'm lost on this.  Been working at different things for about a month and have no clue.
Could someone give some advice to get me started?

BTW the only things I actually need from the XML file are PATIENT id, NAME and EXAM ID.

Comment: First of all, I would totally ignore DataSet. That's old technology and is leading you astray.

Comment: Thanks guys!  This is perfect to get me started.  I'm not sure which method I'll use but I'm definitely heading in the right direction now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPTION A:

Use XDocument to map xml to some basic DTO objects.

[Parent/Children Xml to DTO Object Model with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498467/parent-children-xml-to-dto-object-model-with-linq)

OPTION B:

You can send the xml to a stored procedure directly.

Here is enough of an example to show you how to "shred" the xml into rows.

```
declare @doc xml

select @doc= '

<EXAMS>
    <EXAM id="15" majver="1" minver="1" width="1128" height="910">
        <NAME xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string">Artefact reduced program</NAME>
        <PATIENT id="2" />
        <OBJECTS>
            <TAKE dbid="116" height="1280" width="2648">
                <VIEW majver="1" minver="2" maximized="0" x="0" y="122" width="1124" height="653" vx="199" vy="0" vWidth="2248" vHeight="1280" rotation="0" type="XP" regio="01" position="" orientation="" title="01XP 12.03.05: P1A, Ansicht Artefact reduced prog.." macroDbId="1" flippedHoriz="0" flippedVert="0" inverted="0" brightness="0" contrast="0" xPelsPerMeter="9259" yPelsPerMeter="9259" calibrated="0" calibrationFactor="1000">
                    <PROPERTIES>
                        <PROPERTY name="NGDevicePluginData" value="" />
                        <PROPERTY name="NGPostProcessing" value="" />
                        <PROPERTY name="NGDoseValues" value="" />
                    </PROPERTIES>
                    <DIAGNOSIS x="0" y="136" width="0" height="0" />
                </VIEW>
            </TAKE>
        </OBJECTS>
    </EXAM>
    <EXAM id="16" majver="1" minver="1" width="1128" height="910">
        <NAME xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string">Ceph</NAME>
        <PATIENT id="2" />
        <OBJECTS>
            <TAKE dbid="120" height="2136" width="2808">
                <VIEW majver="1" minver="2" maximized="0" x="4" y="447" width="561" height="440" vx="2" vy="1" vWidth="2805" vHeight="2135" rotation="0" type="XC" regio="03" position="" orientation="" title="03XC 28.07.04: 30x23, Ansicht Ceph" macroDbId="1" flippedHoriz="0" flippedVert="0" inverted="0" brightness="0" contrast="0" xPelsPerMeter="9615" yPelsPerMeter="9615" calibrated="0" calibrationFactor="1000">
                    <PROPERTIES>
                        <PROPERTY name="NGDevicePluginData" value="" />
                        <PROPERTY name="NGPostProcessing" value="" />
                        <PROPERTY name="NGDoseValues" value="" />
                    </PROPERTIES>
                    <DIAGNOSIS x="4" y="460" width="0" height="0" />
                </VIEW>
            </TAKE>
            <TAKE dbid="121" height="2136" width="1756">
                <VIEW majver="1" minver="2" maximized="0" x="598" y="450" width="351" height="440" vx="1" vy="1" vWidth="1755" vHeight="2135" rotation="0" type="XC" regio="04" position="" orientation="" title="04XC 23.08.05: -, Ansicht Ceph" macroDbId="1" flippedHoriz="0" flippedVert="0" inverted="0" brightness="0" contrast="0" xPelsPerMeter="9615" yPelsPerMeter="9615" calibrated="0" calibrationFactor="1000">
                    <PROPERTIES>
                        <PROPERTY name="NGDevicePluginData" value="" />
                        <PROPERTY name="NGPostProcessing" value="" />
                        <PROPERTY name="NGDoseValues" value="" />
                    </PROPERTIES>
                    <DIAGNOSIS x="598" y="463" width="0" height="0" />
                </VIEW>
            </TAKE>
            <TAKE dbid="118" height="2136" width="1756">
                <VIEW majver="1" minver="2" maximized="0" x="1" y="2" width="351" height="440" vx="1" vy="1" vWidth="1755" vHeight="2135" rotation="0" type="XC" regio="01" position="" orientation="" title="01XC 02.09.04: -, Ansicht Ceph" macroDbId="1" flippedHoriz="0" flippedVert="0" inverted="0" brightness="0" contrast="-9" xPelsPerMeter="9615" yPelsPerMeter="9615" calibrated="0" calibrationFactor="1000">
                    <PROPERTIES>
                        <PROPERTY name="NGDevicePluginData" value="" />
                        <PROPERTY name="NGPostProcessing" value="" />
                        <PROPERTY name="NGDoseValues" value="" />
                    </PROPERTIES>
                    <DIAGNOSIS x="1" y="15" width="0" height="0" />
                </VIEW>
            </TAKE>
            <TAKE dbid="119" height="2136" width="1800">
                <VIEW majver="1" minver="2" maximized="0" x="358" y="1" width="360" height="440" vx="0" vy="1" vWidth="1800" vHeight="2135" rotation="0" type="XC" regio="03" position="" orientation="" title="03XC 02.09.04: -, Ansicht Ceph" macroDbId="1" flippedHoriz="0" flippedVert="0" inverted="0" brightness="0" contrast="0" xPelsPerMeter="9615" yPelsPerMeter="9615" calibrated="0" calibrationFactor="1000">
                    <PROPERTIES>
                        <PROPERTY name="NGDevicePluginData" value="" />
                        <PROPERTY name="NGPostProcessing" value="" />
                        <PROPERTY name="NGDoseValues" value="" />
                    </PROPERTIES>
                    <DIAGNOSIS x="358" y="14" width="0" height="0" />
                </VIEW>
            </TAKE>
        </OBJECTS>
    </EXAM>
</EXAMS>
'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes' AS peanut)
SELECT 
      EXAM_ID =         Y.i.value('(../../../../../@id)[1]', 'varchar(40)')
    , DATATYPE_DT =     Y.i.value('(../../../../../NAME/@peanut:dt)[1]', 'varchar(40)')
    , PATIENT_ID =      Y.i.value('(../../../../../PATIENT/@id)[1]', 'varchar(40)')
    , PROPERTY_NAME =   Y.i.value('@name[1]', 'varchar(40)') 
    , PROPERTY_VALUE =  Y.i.value('@value[1]', 'varchar(40)') 
    , DIAGNOSIS_X =     Y.i.value('(../../DIAGNOSIS/@x)[1]', 'varchar(40)') 
FROM 
    @doc.nodes('/EXAMS/EXAM/OBJECTS/TAKE/VIEW/PROPERTIES/PROPERTY') AS Y(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, I think you have most of the solution.
Read the XML file into an XML Document: this object converts your file into a "tree" format.

Then go over (iterate) the resulting tree using the various functions of the reader. During this process you can skip processing those nodes you don't care for and update your database using SQL.

BTW, your XML sample (in the question) is malformed - its missing the closing "EXAMS" tag ;]

here's a code snippet that shows the gist of what you need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.parse();
        }


        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

        public void parse()
        {
            xmldoc.Load("c:\\yourfile.xml");//load your XML file

            //set your starting point
            XmlNodeList xNodelset = xmldoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("EXAM");

            // traverse the XML 
            foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodelset)
            {
                //here's where all the work is done: you can go over nodes, get their value


                //get the exam id attribute:
                int examID = int.Parse(xNode.Attributes[0].Value);

                //and eventually push them to your DB using SQL.
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I would stay away from `XmlDocument` and use LINQ to XML instead. It's much more flexible and easier to use.

Comment: I find that XmlDocument - despite being very verbose - is more intuitive than LINQ. Programmers coming to .Net from other languages don't necessarily want to learn lambda expressions just to parse XML.

Comment: First of all, _real_ programmers had better get used to lambda expressions - even Java has them. Second, I don' typically need to use lambda expressions to use LINQ to XML.