# Read XML Data to GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have XML:

```
<BookList>
  <Book ID="1" Category="Science">
    <Title>test</Title>
    <Price>18.74</Price>
  </Book>
  <Book ID="2" Category="Drama">
    <Title>test2</Title>
    <Price>23.99</Price>
  </Book>
</BookList>
```

And I must use  control `GridView` and display data:

ID | Title

1     test

2     test2

My code:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="productsDataSource" 
                   Runat="server" 
                   DataFile="~/dane.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" 
              DataSourceID="productsDataSource" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" 
                    DataField="ID" 
                    SortExpression="ID">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" 
                    DataField="Title"
                    SortExpression="Title">
    </asp:BoundField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

But I get error: "not found field Title"

Comment: Gridview will not be able to read the xml file as you have defined. You may need to transform the xml file into a form that gridview likes. See this post for the full details https://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/12/22/aspnet-how-to-use-an-xmldatasource-with-a-gridview/

Comment: Its not worth the (xsl) trouble IMHO.  Convert the xml to simple DTO objects.  A parent/child DTO (loaded from xml) can be seen here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498467/parent-children-xml-to-dto-object-model-with-linq